# Which oracle database version is useful for C#?

Tags: c#

I want to use an Oracle database with c#. Please suggest an Oracle version & Oracle-SqlManager (and download source) with which I'd be able to manually create databases and tables.

Comment: Any version? Just get the latest.

Comment: Download? No problem. it is super hidden at the area "Downloads" on http://www.oracle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them.  Oracle is a great database platform (for non MS products) but you really should use SqlServer or MySql instead of Oracle.  The .Net provider from Oracle has always been riddled with bugs which caused our end users countless headaches.